# How do the functional test tools for Flash and Flex applications compare?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have come across the following:

- Flash-Selenium
- RIATest
- Eggplant
- FlexMonkey
- Flex Pilot

What are their respective advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried :

1. RIATest : robust solution, the one we use today. Flex 4 supported as well as AIR. Not free though
2. Flash-selenium : A bit hard to configure, lack of documentation, very few updates
3. FlexMonkey : easy to integrate, open source but not as much robust as RIATest. Documentation could be better. If you need support, you have to pay